# UISearchBar and UINavigationBar from navigation controller disappearing when searching

Tags: ios

I have a UINavigationController with a UISearchBar right under the UINavigationBar. When I click in the search bar, the text and buttons on the UINavigationBar disappears, but the blank white bar still stays. I think this is because it is a navigation controller and so the navigation bar can disappear. In addition, when I start typing, the search bar disappears, but I can still type. My question: is there a way to either make the entire navigation bar disappear when I start searching or make the text on the navigation bar stay while searching, and how do I ensure the search bar does not disappear? Thanks.[image: before I start typing]

[image: when I start typing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In the storyboard, I had to click on the little icon on the bottom, third from the left, then "resolve auto layout issues." Autolayout must be off for this to work

Answer (score 1):

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```